# Mixing Async and Sync in same HTTP request ASP.NET Core C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core

Is it bad practice to mix async and sync call in same ASP.NET core API call?

For example, in following code method `CropBlackBroderOfAnImageAsync` is an async method.

On the other hand `SaveImageForProcessing(file, sourceFolderPath);` is a sync method.

The reason I am calling `SaveImageForProcessing` synchronously is
that I want use the result of it to execute the code in `CropBlackBroderOfAnImageAsync`.

```
public async Task<(string sourceFolderPath, string destinationFolderPath)> CropBlackBorderOfAnImage(IFormFile file)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
    var newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();//Create a new Name for the file due to security reasons.
    var fileNameSource = newFileName + extension;
    var sourceFolderPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images\\Source", fileNameSource);

    var fileNameDestination = newFileName + "Result" + extension;
    var destinationFolderPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images\\Destination", fileNameDestination);

    SaveImageForProcessing(file, sourceFolderPath);

    await _imageCropBlackBroderService.CropBlackBroderOfAnImageAsync(sourceFolderPath, destinationFolderPath);

    return (sourceFolderPath, destinationFolderPath);
}

private void SaveImageForProcessing(IFormFile file, string path)
{
    using (var bits = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        file.CopyTo(bits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please edit your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: You are using `Path.Combine` which is great, but then you hardcode the path delimiter ``\\``. The `Images` and `Source` names should be their own distinct parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Well, generally it is not a problem to call a sync method within async method.

You are actualy doing this in more then few instances (GetExtension, NewGuild, ToString, etc...)

But if you have an async method available it would be shame to not use it.
Which you have - `IFormFile.CopyToAsync()`.

```
using (var bits = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
{
  await file.CopyToAsync(bits);
}
await _imageCropBlackBroderService.CropBlackBroderOfAnImageAsync(sourceFolderPath, destinationFolderPath);
```